# MySql Backslashes disappear when data is updated to another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains directory paths and the data looks like this:

[image]

But when I run an update statement where I join another table to this one and update the to existing rows in the new table, the backslashes disappear like this:

[image]

This is the update statement, where

> "MIJob.SourceFile"

has the proper text containing the backslashes, and

> "MIJobFileLocation.Path_Folder"

is the column being updated and does not have backslashes in its data.

This is the update statement:

```
UPDATE MIJobFileLocation
INNER JOIN MIJob
ON MIJobFileLocation.MIJobFileLocationGUID = MIJob.MIJobFileLocationGUID_Source

SET
MIJobFileLocation.Path_Folder = MIJob.SourceFile
WHERE MIJob.SourceFile IS NOT NULL
```

This SQL will run in a stored procedure in MySQL. How can I preserve the backslashes?

I’ve been googling this for hours with no success.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: Hi @shree.pat18, I added sample code above.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this line before your update statement.  Seems like a hack solution, but it works.

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES'
UPDATE sometable
set.....
```